# How to merge 2 directories without overwriting *different* files with same relative path?

Tags: linux, shell, directory, file-copy, merge

## Example

Suppose I have 2 directories `a/` and `b/`. Let's say they contain the following files:

```
a/
a/foo/1
a/bar/2
a/baz/3

b/
b/foo/1
b/bar/2
```

such that `a/foo/1` and `b/foo/1` are identical but `a/bar/2` and `b/bar/2` are different.

After merging `a/` into `b/`, I want to get:

```
a/
a/bar/2

b/
b/foo/1
b/bar/2
b/baz/3
```

## Explanation

- `a/foo/` and `b/foo/` are (recursively) identical, so we remove `a/foo/`.
- `a/bar/2` and `b/bar/2` are different, so we do nothing.
- `a/baz/` exists only in `a/` but not in `b/`, so we move it to `b/baz/`.

---

Is there a ready-made shell command for this? I have a feeling that `rsync` may work, but I am unfamiliar with `rsync`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't say that I know of a particular command that would do this for you. But you could accomplish this just using hashing.

Naïve example below:

```
#!/bin/bash

# ...some stuff to get the files...

# Get hashes for all source paths
for srcFile in "${srcFileList[@]}"
do
  srcHashList+="$(md5sum "$srcFile")"
done

# Get hashes for all destination paths
for dstFile in "${dstFileList[@]}"
do
  dstHashList+="$(md5sum "$dstFile")"
done

# Compare hashes, exclude identical files, regardless of their path.
for srci in "${!srcHashList[@]}"
do
  for dsti in "${!dstHashList[@]}"
  do
    match=0
    if [ "${srcHashList[$srci]}" == "${dstHashList[$dsti]}" ]
    then
      match=1
    fi
    if [ $match != 1 ]
    then
      newSrcList+=${srcFileList[$srci]}
      newDstList+=${dstFileList[$dsti]}
    fi
  done
done
# ...move files after based on the new lists
```

This could definitely be done cleaner, especially if you only care about files with identical paths to eachother. Could also probably be done in linear time, but the general concept will work.

Comment: Thank you! I was very busy due to real life issues. I will probably follow your idea later and write a command suitable for my use case.

Comment: I wish you luck, just let me know/update your question if you run into issues!